# How to hide the label in the form helper for the play framework?

Tags: java, forms, playframework

I have a form, where the user can enter questions. Every field has a label, but in the production environment I dont want to show the labels and certain inputText fields. I tried to get rid of them by using `'style -> "display: none"` which removes the inputText field but not the label. I did not find an explanation for this on the play framework site: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0.4/JavaFormHelpers

Is there a way to accomplish that with build in tools, or are there other possibilities?

```
@import helper._
@import helper.twitterBootstrap._

@helper.form(action = routes.Application.sendQuestion()){
        <fieldset>
            @helper.inputText(questionForm("questionID"),'style -> "display: none")
            @helper.inputText(questionForm("questionText"))
            @helper.inputText(questionForm("voteScore"))
            @helper.inputText(questionForm("ownerID"))
            @helper.inputText(questionForm("page"))
        </fieldset>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can hide the label in the form write your own field constructor, example:

**Writing you own field constructor**

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span> 
    </div>
</div>
```

For more details - https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers