# Do not display text before input field when using @helper.inputText("property")

Tags: html, css, scala, playframework, attributes

Here is my code:

```
 @helper.inputText(trainerForm("userName"),'class -> "form-control", 'placeholder -> "User name")
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

I would like to stop showing `userName` text. How can I do that?

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30592134/how-to-hide-the-label-in-the-form-helper-for-the-play-framework) is an answer I find somewhat similar. It suggests to create your own constructor and even refers to an actual [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/JavaFormHelpers), but still I do not understand how to do that.

There is no explanation on where should I write the custom constructor and how should I use it in future. Please, explain me the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool -- seems like you found a solution.

Check out the default play constructor [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/defaultFieldConstructor.scala.html)

If you want to create your own, create a template with `@(elements: helper.FieldElements)` as the singular argument:

```
@(elements: FieldElements)

<dl class="@elements.args.get('_class) @if(elements.hasErrors) {error}" id="@elements.args.get('_id).getOrElse(elements.id + "_field")">
    <dd>@elements.input</dd>
    @elements.errors.map { error =>
        <dd class="error">@error</dd>
    }
    @elements.infos.map { info =>
        <dd class="info">@info</dd>
    }
</dl>
```

And then you can create your implicit field contructor.

```
object MyFieldConstructors {
  implicit val custom = FieldConstructor(templateReference.f)
}
```

and be sure to import it into the template where you'd like to use your own constructor:

```
@import path.to.MyFieldConstructors.custom
```

Now any template you import the custom constructor to will use the handler you created.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. Here is the best solution I come up with:

```
 $("dt").remove();
```

You just create .js and write that to it. It will work only if you are using jQuery as well.